# Hackerrank Diagonal Difference Question in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to complete the Diagonal Difference Question of Hackerrank with the following JavaScript code,

```
function diagonalDifference(arr) {
// Write your code here
let right = 0;
let left = 0;
const row = Math.sqrt(arr.length);
for (let i=0; i<arr.length; i=i+row){
        right+= arr[i]
        i++
}
for (let i=row; i<arr.length; i=i+row){
        left+= arr[i-1]
        i--
}

let res = Math.abs(right-left)
return res
```

}

However, the answer keeps coming out as **wrong answer**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3fmcA.png)

Besides, I tried running this code in other IDE's and everything else gives me the correct output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost there, try using one loop instead

```js
const arr = [
  [1, 2, 3],
  [4, 5, 6],
  [7, 8, 9]
]

const diagonalDifference = (arr) => {
  const length = arr.length;
  let left = 0,
    right = 0;

  for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    left += arr[i][i];
    right += arr[length - 1 - i][i]
  }

  console.log(Math.abs(left - right));

  return Math.abs(left - right);
}

diagonalDifference(arr)
```

Comment: Thank you for conveying it in a kind manner and it works!

Answer (score 0):

```js
function diagonalDifference(arr) {
    // Write your code here
    let line1 = 0;
    let line2 = 0;

    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        for (let j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {
            if (i == j) {
            line1 += arr[i][j];
            }
            if (i + j == arr.length - 1) {
            line2 += arr[i][j];
            }
        }
    }
    
    return Math.abs(line1 - line2);
```

Comment: It is a good idea to explain why your answer helps the questioner - by explaining the changes.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

```
function diagonalDifference(arr) {
   let ltr_diagonal = 0;
   let rtl_diagonal = 0;
   for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
       ltr_diagonal += arr[i][i];
       rtl_diagonal += arr[i][arr.length-i-1];
   }
   let result = Math.abs(ltr_diagonal - rtl_diagonal);
   return result;
}
```